# How to use CMAKE for Windows-SDK compiler, when VS2010 is installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, python-2.7, cmake

I am currently devoloping a Python 2.7 frontend using [SWIG](http://swig.org) for a C++ project configured by CMAKE (not developed by myself, I just started CMAKE for this project). The project compiles (and runs) fine under VS2010 using FIND_PACKAGE for python and swig. However, python 2.7 (and other releases) is compiled using the VS2008 compiler, which is not binary compatible with VS2010. I have installed the Windows SDK 7 compiler, and I can compile another SWIG project (without CMAKE) using distutils. Trying to configure the actual project with CMAKE for Visual Studio 2008, fails with:

```
xxx> cmake . -G "Visual Studio 9 2008"
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Visual Studio 9 2008".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.          
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: xxx/CMakeFiles/2.8.12/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake                                                    
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: xxx/CMakeFiles/2.8.12/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
```

(I replaced my actual path with xxx)

This happens both in the Windows-SDK shell, as well as in a normal shell.

Has anybody configured a CMAKE project successfully for Windows SDK 7 compiler, when another VS version is installed? If yes, how?
Finally I would rather use a CMAKE configured python distutils build, than build the project using a generated .sln file. Hence, creating a VS2008 .sln / .prj is not important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just open the SDK command prompt, so the cl.exe you want (in the VS 2008 install directory) is in PATH (you can check this is the case with `where cl`).

Then just run CMake and let it generate NMake makefiles:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles"
```

This should ensure your compiler of choice is used.

If this doesn't work either, the SDK (or VS) should come with a tool to make a certain SDK version "current".

Comment: You can also use the CMake GUI interface. It allows you to select the build environment when you try to configure.

Comment: And you can use the  "Visual Studio 2010" generator and use msbuild on the commandline.

Comment: @linello I didn't know CMake came with a Graphical User Interface interface `;-)`.

Comment: "Visual Studio <n>" doesn't work if only SDK is installed.

Comment: @ ivan_pozdeev, Visual Studio <n>" can  work if you run cmake from the shortcut command line tool provided by SDK 7 which set the environment of toolset.